# Show that $\overline A \cap \overline B \not\subseteq \overline {A \cap B}$ using definition

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, proof-writing

It is well known that $\overline {A \cap B} \neq \overline A \cap \overline B$

> I wish to show that $\overline A \cap \overline B \not\subseteq
> \overline {A \cap B}$ by using the definition (instead of proof by counter example)

Note 1. Reverse case $\overline {A \cap B} \subseteq \overline A \cap \overline B$ is trivial

Note 2. the definition of closure I am using is one in Munkres:

> $x \in \overline A \iff \text{ for every open set } U \text{
>  containing } x, U \cap A \neq \varnothing$

Wrong proof:

- Let $x \in \overline A \cap \overline B$, then $x \in \overline A$
  and $x \in \overline B$

  - Therefore $\forall U \in \tau, x \in U \implies U \cap A \neq
       \varnothing \text{ and } U \cap B \neq \varnothing$

    - So  $\forall U \in \tau, x \in U \implies U \cap A \cap  U \cap B
      \neq \varnothing \implies U \cap (A\cap B) \neq \varnothing$

      - Therefore $x \in \overline {A\cap B}$

Where did I go wrong in the above?

Comment: $\overline{A} \cap \overline{B} \subseteq \overline{A \cap B}$ holds sometimes, so it's going to be hard to prove what you want.

Comment: @Hoot I see...so counter example is the only way

Comment: The first statement is wrong, if you have $(1,3)$ and $(2,4)$ then $\overline{(1,3)\cap(2,4)}=\overline{(1,3)}\cap\overline{(2,4)}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're managing to confuse yourself slightly by not representing the quantifiers on $A$ and $B$ explicitly.

Apparently you know that it is *not* the case that
$$ \tag{1} \forall A,B : \overline A\cap \overline B \subseteq \overline{A\cap B} $$
However, you seem to be confusing that fact with
$$ \tag{2} \forall A,B : \neg(\overline A\cap \overline B \subseteq \overline{A\cap B})$$
but the actual negation of (1) is
$$ \tag{3} \neg \forall A,B : \overline A\cap \overline B \subseteq \overline{A\cap B}$$
which is the same as
$$ \tag{3'} \exists A,B : \neg(\overline A\cap \overline B \subseteq \overline{A\cap B})$$

Of the above claims, (2) is false (just consider the case where $A=B$; then both sides reduce to $\overline A$.

(3), on the other hand, is true, and in the form (3') we can see that one example is indeed all you need to prove it.

Something like $A=\mathbb Q$, $B=\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q$ should do.

---

The error in your wrong proof is that you can't reason from $U\cap A\ne\varnothing$ and $U\cap B\ne \varnothing$ to $(U\cap A)\cap(U\cap B)\ne\varnothing$. Just because each of the two sets is nonempty doesn't mean they have any elements *in common*!